# How to increment and format integer in results table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read many posts related to this issue but unfortunately none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

I am trying to set up a SQL statement that would create a column in my results table with values formatted as follows:

date + 8 digit number incremented by 1 for each new record and prefixed with leading zeros.

In other words, I would like to have a column with data in the following format:

```
    2015061000000001
    2015061000000002
    2015061000000003
    2015061000000004
    2015061000000005
    ...
```

I tried using `row_number()` as well as a local variable but I am not having much luck getting this to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
    declare @a int;
    set @a = 1;

    select 
        'aaa',                          
        (select (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)) + RIGHT('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,2),8)),
        row_number() over(order by id), 
        (select (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)) + RIGHT('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( row_number() over(order by id) )),8)),
        (select (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)) + RIGHT('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( select @a + 1 )),8))
    FROM MY_TABLE
```

Results table:

```
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 1 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 2 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 3 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 4 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 5 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 6 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 7 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
    aaa | 2015061000000002 | 8 | 2015061000000001 | 2015061000000002
```

Could anyone please advise how to get to return this?

```
    2015061000000001
    2015061000000002
    2015061000000003
    2015061000000004
    2015061000000005
    ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Although the question is already answered, a small addition for the record: your statement with row_number was correct, however it shouldn't have been used in a subquery column. That caused the row_number to return 1 each time. If you'd have removed the select from `(select (CONVERT.....row_number()...`, it would have worked. In other words, the row_number used was not the same as your current row_number column `row_number() over(order by id)`, but would have been the same as a column `(select row_number() over(order by id))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right path, just need a little push...
Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112) + 
       RIGHT('0000000'+ 
       CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t_Id) As varchar(8))
       ,8)
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
        'aaa',    
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) + 
        RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR(8)), 8)            
  FROM yourTable
```

Concatenate the result from `ROW_NUMBER` with 7 `'0'`s so as to be sure that you will always have *at least* 8 digits, then select exactly 8 starting from the rightmost digit.

Answer (score 3):

Or even stranger:

```
    , CONVERT( nvarchar(20), CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 112) AS decimal(20,0)) * POWER( 10,8) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by id))
```

Comment: Nice... Too many conversions, and I would add line breaks to make more readable, though.

Comment: I'm afraid the conversions are needed for a column with this width using this way of calculating the value. At least it does not do to many string operations which tends to be better for SQL performance.

Comment: I don't see any performance issues with neither suggestions. tested on 10000 rows they both have the exact same execution plan and query cost is the same.